# Convert spread operator from javascript t typescript functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

I cannot convert that piece of code from Javascript to Typescript.

The problem is converting the ...spread operator.

```
function calculateCombinations(first, next, ...rest) {

  if (rest.length) {
    next = calculateCombinations(next, ...rest);
  }


  return first.flatMap(a => next.map(b => [a, b].flat()));
}


a1 = ['A', 'B']
a2 = ['+', '-']
a3 = ['1', '2']
a4 = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
// Show possibile combinations
calculateCombinations(a1, a2, a3, a4); // give me an array of 24 combinations
```

*Attempt to conversion to TS:*

```
  function calculateCombinationsTS(first: any[], next: any[], ...rest: any[]) {
    if (rest.length) {
        next = calculateCombinationsTS(next, ...rest);
    }

   return first.flatMap(a => next.map(b => [a, b].flat()));
  }
```

**TS2556: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.**

If I change

```
 next = calculateCombinationsTS(next, ...rest);
```

to

```
 next = calculateCombinationsTS(next, rest);
```

the function give me a wrong result, because rest is passed as array of array instead of a list of arguments

**Example of output:**

```
nCombo = (a1 * a2 * a3 * a4) = 24 possibilities
[
  [ 'A', '+', '1', 'X' ], [ 'A', '+', '1', 'Y' ],
  [ 'A', '+', '1', 'Z' ], [ 'A', '+', '2', 'X' ],
  [ 'A', '+', '2', 'Y' ], [ 'A', '+', '2', 'Z' ],
  [ 'A', '-', '1', 'X' ], [ 'A', '-', '1', 'Y' ],
  [ 'A', '-', '1', 'Z' ], [ 'A', '-', '2', 'X' ],
  [ 'A', '-', '2', 'Y' ], [ 'A', '-', '2', 'Z' ],
  [ 'B', '+', '1', 'X' ], [ 'B', '+', '1', 'Y' ],
  [ 'B', '+', '1', 'Z' ], [ 'B', '+', '2', 'X' ],
  [ 'B', '+', '2', 'Y' ], [ 'B', '+', '2', 'Z' ],
  [ 'B', '-', '1', 'X' ], [ 'B', '-', '1', 'Y' ],
  [ 'B', '-', '1', 'Z' ], [ 'B', '-', '2', 'X' ],
  [ 'B', '-', '2', 'Y' ], [ 'B', '-', '2', 'Z' ] 
]
```

Comment: Yes, I've put a sample of output

Comment: I've updated the question with a small number of combinations avoiding a too complex example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. If you want to pass a series of array arguments for your rest parameter, you rest parameter must be an array of arrays, not just an array. So: `...rest: any[][]`. TypeScript isn't complaining about that because you can use an array for `any`, but it's a more accurate reflection of what you're doing.
2. TypeScript can't tell that the call `calculateCombinationsTS(next, ...more);` will pass an argument for `next` to the function, even though you have a check on `rest.length` and so *you* know it will. You need to call the function with two discrete arguments, followed (optionally) by spreading an array. You can fix that by grabbing the first element from the `rest` parameter and passing it explicitly:

   ```
   if (rest.length) {
       const [first, ...more] = rest;
       next = calculateCombinationsTS(next, first, ...more);
   }
   ```

   In theory, that might add overhead. In practice, I suspect the overhead will be sufficiently optimized to not be an issue.

   Or, since you **know** the call is correct (because you know `rest` has at least one element in it), you could silence the error with a `@ts-ignore`, but I try to avoid those where I can.

Complete function fixing both issues:

```
function calculateCombinationsTS(first: any[], next: any[], ...rest: any[][]) {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^
   if (rest.length) {
       const [first, ...more] = rest;                        // ***
       next = calculateCombinationsTS(next, first, ...more); // ***
   }

   return first.flatMap((a) => next.map((b) => [a, b].flat()));
}
```

[Runnable playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhgGwiNKoFMDCcAtgEYxg7xgDOAKgMoAUwMATtVAFyIpgCeAbQC6AGkRhcADy49+wsQDolrXB269BQ4QEpEAbwBQiY4hjBEjFRwVpcYAOZQAFrsMn3yBB0QCW7KIpKRHAqQogAvIhWUADcRh7GEtIRyOiY2HiEpOSUXgyMSQGIfhyBCsEq2nHuAL4G8cYqUCCsSCVQCsAZALIoAA6MjCi64QB84lIdRP2DJCPjAihiJEKdGYzam3F1BhBeUDwAjCkCAEQop2KnJJeIpxCnQnF7NAcoAEwnpwAmt6e4j2e+x4AGYvsBAbtgSgACxfex-Jx-GB-NCQl7eFAAVi+kj+fD+AC90cCrFgDpFUBgsDgCMQyBRYHkmChDmIPuyQeyYeysVUoTQ4LYbHB7IwAAZktAdWwOZwpAAkeilMrsjicNXF-IxQtwIrFKqqQA) generating the 72 combinations from your example

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
next = calculateCombinationsTS(next, rest[0], ...rest.slice(1));
```

Typescript will be happier if you explicitly call the function with the same signature (first, next, ...spread).

Comment: I didn't downvote it (actually I just did the opposite), but I suspect it's because the lack of meaningful explanation. Code dumps are not usually useful answers, it's much better to say *what* you did, *why*, and how it solves the problem. But yes, this would solve the issue with the code the OP asked about.

Comment: I confirm that also your code works.

Comment: Thank you, @T.J.Crowder. I'm new to this and my answer was too brief. I'll take note to improve! (your own answer is a great example of a well explained solution)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is how you call the function, that is not a problem from TypeScript.

`calculateCombinations` wants 2 required arguments, then some others, but you're sending only one required argument when you're calling it again recursively.

When you say `calculateCombinations(next, ...rest)` TypeScript thinks `next: any[]` should be a spread operator

Comment: The test on `rest.length` ensures that the recursive call is correct. (It's just TypeScript doesn't know that.)

Comment: I don't know why there is this error, but one thing sure: the TypeScript issue goes away when sending 3 arguments at least

Comment: With 3 argument Typescript doesnt show error, but the result of function is wrong

Comment: I know it is not working properly, all I want to say is that writing 3 arguments solves the problem, then he can adjust the thing how it must be done

Comment: Doesn't work: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: lmao my comment just wants to explain why this TypeScript warning happens